# Looking for a manhwa with child protagonists centering around a female lead, more details inside

Tags: story-identification, comics, manga, webcomics

What I remember: There's a chapter 0, and the scene that stood out is the FL (child female lead), had slept in the same bed as a dark haired boy, and the boy was saying something along the lines of "I will take responsibility" when he woke up and saw her in bed.

The boy is trapped in a tower and the girl usually sends her familiar (some sorta magic pet) to help him fall asleep. I think her hair is light colored.

One plot point might be that she has two types of magic that conflict, and some deity (long black haired mage type) who can look like an adult or child helps her (might be confusing another manhwa, if you recognize one with this character lemme know)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?

Comment: He's trapped in a tower - is this like a regular room, just locked up, or closer to a prison/torture chamber. About how old are the characters supposed to be? Does this "I will take responsibility" scene occur in chapter 0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first part is probably [Surviving as the illegitimate(/bastard) princess](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/mizfu0f/surviving-as-the-illegitimate-princess)

We have protagonist that constantly dies and returns to her childchood, she wants revenge on her father who always pretends to not know they are family, later gets to know a boy that is imprisoned in tower because he is prince of enemy country. Girl has a conflict between her uncommon holy magic and more common regular magic, but manages to survive it with help of her father.

The deity part doesn't match, so probably is from different manhwa.